# TileCache and MapServer layer type - how to specify MapServer URL?

Tags: mapserver, tilecache

I'm trying to wrap TileCache into a Docker container. But it looks like there is no way to specify the URL for the mapserver.
According to TileCache docs I can only specify 'url' parameter for WMS and other layers, but not for "MapServer" ( raster tiles ) type. I did try using 'url' parameter just in case, but it did not work. Looks like it's trying to fetch a tile from some "internal" URL and is getting a timeout.

Below is my TileCache config file:

```
# Configuration for MC TileCache
[cache]
type=Disk
base=/path/to/cache

# States TEST
[layer_zp520201iach]
type=MapServer
url=https://myserver/cgi-bin/mapserv
layers=layer_zp520201iach
srs=epsg:900913
#bbox=-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34
spherical_mercator=true
mapfile=/path/to/mapfile/mapfile.map
metaTile=true
metaSize=5,5
metaBuffer=350
```

Am I missing something? Is there actually No way to define MapServer URL for MapServer layer type?

Comment: MapCache is built specifically for MapServer, and is therefore recommended. https://mapserver.org/mapcache/

Answer (score 0):

Tilecache 2.11 calls Mapserver via Mapscript ( not via TCP/IP ), and thus (afaik) I have to keep Mapserver and Tilecache within same Docker container.